# Cannot assign value of type ‘[model]’ to type ‘Model’

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I want to display the value of the table view cell on the screen. However, the following error occurs:
**Cannot assign value of type ‘[listenings]’ to type ‘ProfileModel’**
I think there is no problem with the model.

```
func bindViewModel() {
        let input = ListenViewModel.input(loadData: loadData.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: ()))
        let output = viewModel.transform(input)
        
        output.loadApplyList.map(CollectionOfOne.init).bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { tableView, index, element -> UITableViewCell in
            guard let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListeningTableViewCell") as? ListeningTableViewCell else {
                return ListeningTableViewCell()
            }
            cell.listeningData = element.listen
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
    }
```

This is my ViewController code. Error occurs in 'cell.listingdata large = element.listen'

```
class target: Codable {
    let nickname: String
    let image: String
    let listening: Int
    let listener: Int
    let isMine: Bool
}

class listen: Codable {
    let listen: [listenings]
}

class listenings: Codable {
    let nickname: String
    let image: String
    let listener: Int
    let listening: Int
    let isListening: Int
}
```

And this is my Model code.
How to solve this error?

Comment: The error clearly says that the type of `cell.listeningData` is not `[listenings]` – by the way please name structs with starting uppercase letter – it's `ProfileModel`

Comment: Do you mean change to 'cell.listeningData = Element.Listen'? The following changes have been made to the model: `class Listen: Codable { let listen: [listenings] }`

Comment: The problem is not the naming, the problem is the type mismatch. As I said `listeningData` is `ProfileModel` whatever this is.

Comment: `class ProfileModel: Codable {
    let nickname: String
    let image: String
    let listener: Int
    let listening: Int
    let Listening: Bool
}

class listening: Codable {
    let listening: [ProfileModel]
}
` This is ProfileModel code.Which part is the problem?

Comment: @eath Do you know what the square brackets in `[listenings]` means?

Comment: Array..?? If not, could you tell me what it is?

Comment: Once again: `cell.listeningData` is `ProfileModel` but `element.listen` is `[listenings]`. It's a double type mismatch, different types and single object vs. array.